# How can I read different groups of data on the same InputStream, using different types of InputStreams for each of them?

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream, regex-lookarounds

I needed to save some data in Java in various ways, to a `File`, to a `String`, to `System.out`... And I ended up with 3 methods doing pretty much the same thing. So I changed them into a single method with an `OutputStream` as a parameter. I wrote a few things to a single OutputStream, e.g. some text, a serialized object, another serialized object, some numerical data ...

But now I'm stuck. I overlooked the fact that I cannot distinguish between the different things that have been written. I create an `InputStream` for the data. I use a `Scanner` on that stream to read the text first, and then I tried using an ObjectInputStream to read the serialized objects, but I get an `EOFException`.

I guess that the Scanner reads ahead. How can I prevent the scanner to read ahead.
Or rather, how can I read each group of data using an appropriate InputStream for each of them.

Comment: So you have an InputStream from which you want to read using a Scanner *and* an ObjectInputStream?

Comment: yes, if that is possible

Comment: You have to decide whether it is text e.g. Scanner or binary e.g. ObjectInputStream.  You can mix them if you really know what you are doing but this is unlikely to be a good idea. i.e. its more likely to be a terrible mess.

Comment: You mean I should use one type of data, like text only? If I were to convert the binary data to text, then I could parse it all using a single Scanner. I would then need to find a way to get the objects from the textual data inside a String.

Comment: All text is data, but not all data is text.  So if you need to mix text and data in a stream, then treat your text as data and not the other way around.  So to answer your question: no, don't convert the binary data to text; instead, convert the text data to binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't want to try using different readers to read from the same stream. Even if you manage to get it working on your machine, it might break when you run it on a different OS or with a different JVM implementation.

You should choose a single method of reading and writing data. Since you're using serialized objects in the stream you're probably best off using that for everything. You already pointed out in your comments that it would be very difficult to read binary data in through a string and interpret it correctly. However, it's not hard to take a String object, write it out on the output stream, read it back in and cast it as a String.

Now there's the problem of interpreting your data. I suggest writing everything out in tag-data pairs. You write out an Integer first (maybe the ordinal of an enum to make them easier to use in your program), then you write  out your data. The integer represents the type of data that's coming next in the stream (e.g. either Text or Object), and then the next object you read in is the data and you know what type it is. If it is Text you can cast the object to a String, and pass it into a Scanner, and if it's an object then you just do whatever you need to do with the object.

To make things a bit cleaner you could build a wrapper around the stream with a method for each data type. Maybe you could have a `getNextObject()` method and a `getNextTextScanner()`  method. Each would first check the next Integer tag in the stream to make sure it's reading the right data (throwing an exception if it finds a mismatch), and then would either return the next Object or return a new Scanner for processing a String of data.

Really, it would be better if you could use separate streams for the two different types of data. But, if you're really stuck using the same stream then that's how I'd do it.

Comment: This is a nice, clear answer. I have tried to implement those custom streams. The problem is that serialization, as far as I know, can only be done through an ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream. The implementation of these classes seems to rely a great deal on the JVM. They're not pure java code. I apparently can't recreate their behavior without inventing my own serialization mechanism, which I don't want.. It seems I will need to use those streams under the hood. I will try to get it working tomorrow.