# Java: Possible to have more than one type of stream?

Tags: java, networking, io, stream, protocols

Wondering if one can do something like this successfully:

```
Socket s = new Socket("", 1234);
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
```

Or if there's perhaps a better way of doing it. I ask because I want to send raw data over the Buffered I/O streams and use the Object streams as a means of communicating details and establishing a protocol for connection for my program. Right now I'm trying to just use the Buffered streams and use `byte` arrays for my client/server protocol but I've hit a hiccup where the `byte` array I receive is not equal to what I expect it to be, so the `==` operator and `.equals()` method do not work for me.

Comment: Did you try? Are you having any issues?

Comment: @Nambari I have tried this before on a different project and that didn't work well. I came here to ask if there's a best practice in these situations before I go and mess up my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go take a look at [How can I read different groups of data on the same InputStream, using different types of InputStreams for each of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110523/how-can-i-read-different-groups-of-data-on-the-same-inputstream-using-different) and see if my answer over there helps. It involves tagging the data in an ObjectStream in order to know if it's text or an object.

Comment: Thanks, I've had a look and I might be able to do something like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a mix of streams because they are both buffered so you will get corruption and confusion.

Just use the ObjectStreams for everything.

In general, you should only read from or write to one Stream, Reader or Writer for a stream.

Comment: That's what I was wondering. In that case is it possible to stream data read from a file over an ObjectStream? I see it has a `write(byte[])` method, does that work the same way as the BufferedStreams?

Comment: You can use all the methods of ObjectStream, you just have to be sure that you readObject what you writeObject and you readFully(byte[]) the same data you write(byte[]). If you mix these up you all get corruption. You can send a flag like writeInt(length) and if the length is negative its an Object.